# How to connect 2 Virtual Network with on-premises without another VPN?

Tags: networking, azure, virtual-network

I'm totally new to Azure (and new to any public cloud, never did anything there).

There is one productive virtual network with VPN connection to on-premises resources.
Goal is to create new resource group with new virtual network and connect it with productive virtual network and on-premises resources. But how to achieve this? I've connected two VNets with network peering and it works but I still don't have access to on-premises things.

Do I have to create another VPN connection? I've read something about routing (here: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-networks-udr-overview) but it looks to complex to me.

Also I tried this: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/tutorial-create-route-table-portal but I was stuck in the middle not knowing what to do (and trying not to break production VNet as well).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, when you have two VNETs and your VNG (VPN connection) is only in one VNET, you should create the second VNET to use a remote gateway and your current VNET must accepts a transit gateway. Basically your connection from VNET (without VPN and VNG) will use remote gateway in VNET where you have VNG and your VPN to on-primeses. To make it easier to understand, please have a look at this documentation https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/vpn-gateway-peering-gateway-transit.

It looks like this topology, site S2S VPN (site to site VPN) is connect to HUB (your VNET with VPN / VNG) and site Spoke-RM would be your second VNET (new one).

[image]

Basically you should have this configuration in your VNET where you have VPN, VNG (Virtual Network Gateway), LNG (Local Network Gateway) and GatewaySubnet.

[image]

In this VNET where you have VNG and VPN, go to Peering configuration, this option must be selected. From the blade Peering in this VNET, you must enable `Allow gateway transit` option. It allows traffic from the other VNET to connect to this GatewaySubnet.

[image]

From the other VNET in Peering configuration where you don't have VNG / VPN, you must select this option `Use remote gateways`. It allows this VNET to use remote gateway `GatewaySubnet` in the VNET with VNG / VPN.

[image]

Here it is my test. Below you see route table of my VM in VNET2.

[image: network-test]

From my VPN device on local network (on-premises), you must have route to both address space of your VNETs as I mentioned in the comments. I'm using Windows Server like a VPN site to site, but you should have a firewall where you configured your VPN site to site.

[image: onprem]

Comment: Thank you for your answer! But I cannot check "Allow gateway transit" while adding peering. It's blank for me. In VNET2 (this one is without VPN) I don't have any gateways. In VNET1 (with VPN) I see two gateways. One Virtual Network Gateway and one Local Network Gateway.
When I got into "Connections" of each of them I can see that they're linked togehter.  
Local Network Gateway is is S2S connected with Virtual network gateway.  On the other side Virtual network gateway is connected S2S with peer Local Network Gateway.

Comment: Please finding my update in my answer and let me know if it is better to understand what you are supposed to do :)

Comment: First time I did it the other way around. Now I did it properly like you said but it doesn't work for me.
I can ping local machine from VNET1 (where is VPN) and I can ping machines between VENT1 and VNET2 using local addreses - but I cannot ping local machine form VNET2.

Comment: Go to Network Watcher resource on Azure (search by this name on the search field), there is an option IP FLOW. From this menu you can see IP FLOW from your source (VNET2) to destination (local machine), make sure that traffic from VNET2 to local machine is passing through VNET1. You should see something like GLOBAL/LOCAL Virtual Network Peering, in case you see only Virtual Network as next hop, it means that traffic is ending up VNET2.

Comment: Another option, go to your NIC (network interface) of your VM for both VNET, you can see an option EFFECTIVE ROUTES, make sure that exists route table for all of your addresses IP (local machine, vnet1 and vnet2).

Comment: VNET1 and VNET2 are in different subscriptions. Could this be problem?

Network watcher
I used IP Flow like you said and it looks like this:
https://i.imgur.com/q4vrjzP.png (inbound)
https://i.imgur.com/oMkw88p.png (outbound)
These two screenshots are from VNET2 (one without VPN). The same output is from testing VNET1. But I cannot see there anything like GLOBAL/LOCAL Virtual Network Peering.

Next hops:
VNET1: https://i.imgur.com/TsrmLmM.png
VNET2: https://i.imgur.com/9MG0kuB.png

NIC Effective routes
VNET1: https://i.imgur.com/syIUup5.png
VNET2: https://i.imgur.com/v0d5AWg.png

Comment: I don't have idea what could be problem there because for me everything looks the same.

Comment: Please find my update in the answer, you must verify your on premises device which you have configured your VPN to Azure. All of your images are the same in my test, everything looks fine for me. Make sure that your on premises device VPN is routing traffic to 10.10.0.0/16 and 10.0.0.0/16 through tunnel VPN. You can try a traceroute from 192.168.2.0/24 to 10.x.x.x.x to Azure. Disable all firewall for testing it, just in case.

Comment: Ok, I'll check routing on on-premises device but unfortunately for now I don't have access to it. Probably I'll get access in a week or something. I'll let you know if this worked :)

Answer (score 0):

I have the same scenario but my hub and spoke vnets both are in different subscription and for me (use the remote virtual network's gateway or route server) option grey out .So what could be the reason.
Can't we do the such type of peering for different subscription.Please share your thoughts.